# Android studio build failed. Could not find method allprojects() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to build my ionic application on Android using Capacitor. But when I tried to build and run an application on android studio, it gives this error. I don't have any android studio knowledge. The error:

Could not find method allprojects() for arguments [build_al8rrgnflynwtjpadzojip71i$_run_closure1@68017a4f] on settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

The build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of allprojects in root project gradle, there is another repositories block in dependencyResolutionManagement, which worked for me.